# Mouse click event on generated textboxes in c#

Tags: c#, textbox, mouseevent

I am new to programming and c# so I would appreciate it if the answer to my question comes along with the resources you are using.

My code generates textboxes with each mousedown on the form. And I would like to close the current form and open another form when I (double)click on the generated texboxes.

Thanks in advance!

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnText.Checked)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            tb.Width = 75;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an event handler to your Textbox's `DoubleClick` event

```
tb.DoubleClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2;
            f2.Show();
            this.Close();
        };
```

Note: `Form2` is just for example.You should change it with your second Form's name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subscribe to an event, you can do it inline when you create the control.

This will close the form when you double-click on it:

```
tb.MouseDoubleClick += (s, e) =>
  {
      Close();
      new YourForm().Show();
  }
```

Note: If `Form1` (like in your example) is your main form (the first one your app loads), then as soon as you call `Close()` your entire application will close.